# java cut file extension from url

Tags: java, regex, string, url

I need to cut file extension from urls like this:

```
http://static.gazeta.ru/nm2012/fonts/light/pts_regular_caption.svg#PTSans-CaptionBold

http://2.cdn.echo.msk.ru/assets/../fonts/echo_font-v5.eot#iefix
```

So I want to get 'svg' and 'eot'. 
Im  doing it like this(note that I want to avoid all spec chars not only "#"):

```
 String extension = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf(".") + 1) ;   //cut after dot path
     extension = extension.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", ";");   // replace all special character on ";"

        if(extension.indexOf(";") > 0) {
            extension = extension.substring(0, extension.indexOf(";")); // cut extension before first spec. char
        }
```

But maybe I can do it faster?

Comment: Use `URI` class to parse the URL into its parts, take the path and split by `/`, then look for the extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this,

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[^/.]*\\.(\\w+)[^/]*$").matcher(s);
if(m.find())
{
System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bQ3hM3/1)

Comment: This will give wrong result for URL like `example.com/#/path/do.nothing`